# rvest html_nodes function returning list of 0

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

Okay to start, I'm very new to web scraping. I'm trying to learn and I thought I'd start with something simple - scraping a paragraph of text from a webpage. The webpage I'm trying to scrape is https://www.cato.org/blog

I'm just trying to scrape the first paragraph that begins with "Border patrol arrests..."
I added the SelectorGadget extension to chrome to get the CSS selector.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
url <- "https://www.cato.org/blog"
webpage <- read_html(url)

text <- html_nodes(webpage, "p")

text <- html_text2(text)
```

However, after running `text <- html_nodes(webpage, "p")`, I just get an empty list. No errors or anything just... nothing. Am I doing something wrong? When I look up similar issues, I find answers recommending trying the RSelenium package but when I look up this package and how to use it for my task, a lot of it goes over my head.

Comment: Tricky target. Rvest does not always retrieve the same content as your browser.  To check what rvest has actually received, you can use for example `xml2::html_structure(webpage)` or  `as.character(webpage)`. With html_structure you can check response structure, converting to character allows you to see raw content.  For that particular site it's probably easier to get some results with RSelenium, even if you haven't had a chance to work with Selenium before. https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/

Comment: Are there any beginner Selenium instructions you can recommend? I've looked at several and they all give different instruction on how to initiate selenium and I haven't been able to follow any of them or get them to work for me.

Comment: I'd start with official Vignettes and would pick Docker for running Selelnium Server, though they have some rather old versions still in documentation, meaning that instead of `selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1` it might make sense to use just `selenium/standalone-firefox` to get the latest image.  And there's this thing with Docker images, selenium/standalone-firefox size is over 1GB (in addition to Docker installation which takes it's own chunk).